NextJS The provided export path '/' doesn't match the '/[...slug]' page
I have a peculiar setup with NextJS, so a valid answer to this question could be "You shouldn't do it that way."
My project is a NextJS 15 app (using the app router), combined with the Fumadocs framework to build a documentation website. By default, Fumadocs provides a route /docs/[...slug]/page.js to catch and render all MD documents provided and configured.
All is well but our requirements are (if possible) to remove the docs subdir from the path and only render the landing page (from /app/(home)) on the root '/' and render anything else (if there is no other stricter path matching) as a document. In addition to that, we need to deploy the application with a prepended basePath.
Running a dev instance works without hickups, but when building the output files:
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error     
Error: The provided export path '/' doesn't match the '/[...slug]' page.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-path-mismatch
    at getParams (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\helpers\get-params.js:27:15)
    at exportPageImpl (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:108:43)
    at C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:350:108
    at turborepoTraceAccess (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\build\turborepo-access-trace\helpers.js:36:51)
    at C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:350:103
    at Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:157:26)
    at exportPage (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:350:39) 
    at exportPageWithRetry (C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:239:21)
    at C:\git\adinsure-docs-fumadocs-test\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:321:72
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
Export encountered an error on /[...slug]/page: /, exiting the build.
 ⨯ Static worker exited with code: 1 and signal: null
error Command failed with exit code 1.

This is my next.conifg.mjs
import { createMDX } from 'fumadocs-mdx/next';

const withMDX = createMDX();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const config = {
  output: 'standalone',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  basePath: '/rnd',
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    basePath: '/rnd'
  },
};

export default withMDX(config);

And my project structure is as follows:
.
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │   ├── (home)/
│   │   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   │   └── page.ts
│   │   ├── [...slug]/
│   │   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   ├── layout.config.tsx (fumadocs thing)
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── project.json
├── next.config.mjs
└── ...

And in case you need the /app/[...slug.js]/page.tsx:
imports...

export default async function Page(props: {
  params: Promise<{ slug?: string[] }>;
}) {
...
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return source.generateParams();
}

export async function generateMetadata(props: {
  params: Promise<{ slug?: string[] }>;
}) {
  const params = await props.params;
  const page = source.getPage(params.slug);
  if (!page) notFound();

  return {
    title: page.data.title,
    description: page.data.description,
  };
}


So I also found a peculiar workaround, just delete the .next folder in the project. It does not work every time and I have no idea why it would work or be a problem. Just posting this so that if anyone else has the same issue. But I would still accept an explanation of this :)
